# Rvest - Mismatch between retrieved html and actual site html

Tags: r, rvest

I have a script which regularly checks (once a week) some website to perform scraping. The website is updated once a week (or once every two weeks). Up till now, I've had no issue retrieving the correct information.

Yet today, for some unknown reason, I am getting the wrong information from `read_html`

```
library(rvest)
urlATP <- "http://www.tennisleader.fr/classement/1"
checkDate <- as.Date(gsub("Au ", "",
                          html_text(html_nodes(read_html(urlATP), ".date-atp"))), 
                          format = "%d/%m/%Y")
print(checkDate)
```

Which returns this

```
[1] "2018-07-02"
```

But when I get to the website however, the date is different.

```
<p class="date-atp">Au 16/07/2018</p>
```

What could explain this mismatch and more importantly how do I get rid of it ?

Additional information :

- The date retrieved was the one present on the website last week
- I have tried to clear memory / refresh R session but with no success

Comment: Because sites can generate DOM nodes dynamically with javascript. What does "view source" tell you vs Selector Gadget (which I'm assuming you used or the "elements" view from Developer Tools, both of which are considered harmful).